# Unit testing in Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a C++ UWP unit testing project for a UWP C++ static library, in a C++ Windows 10 UWP App, in a Visual Studio 2015 solution. I'm using the unit testing built-in to VS 2015. It worked perfectly for months and then one day, I get this message when I tried to run the tests from the test explorer:

> DEP3000 : Attempts to stop the application failed. This may cause the
>   deployment to fail. Exception from HRESULT: 0x92330047

After that, unit testing stopped working in Visual Studio. This is what I have attempted to remedy this situation so far:

1. Manually delete the old deployed unit testing app.
2. Manually deploy the unit testing app.
3. Run the "repair" option on the VS 2015 installer.
4. Uninstall and reinstall VS 2015.
5. Use the VisualStudioUninstaller from GitHub and then reinstall VS 2015.
6. A MVP on the MSDN forums looked at the installer logs and said everything installed correctly according to the logs.
7. Made a new solution with a new unit testing project.

The unit testing app launches, the test app window comes up for a minute or two, and then the app closes. However, the test explorer window is left with that busy bar rotating waiting for a response from the test app (I assume).

I have three development machines. The unit testing has stopped working in the same manner on two of them. One is left. The only thing I haven't done is erase the drive and reinstall Windows 10 (and everything else) from scratch. Before I did that (or switched to another unit testing framework) I thought I'd check here if anyone on Stack Overflow knows how to fix this problem. It seems as though something got stomped on in the registry or a configuration file VS has squirreled away somewhere, but I have no idea where to look.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: After posting this I found there are similar questions. I searched first, but I didn't use a good query. Anyway, I'll leave this up since I do give more details regarding what **doesn't** fix the problem.

Comment: I've submitted this issue to Microsoft's developer tech support for Visual Studio. After doing a remote session with them, they said that they have never seen a machine do this before. Well...I have two of them doing that. Anyway, if MS finds a fix, I'll be sure to post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am answering my own question, but it's an answer nevertheless. I spent ten weeks working with Microsoft's Visual Studio tech support (letting them remotely access my system to run test programs and produce log files). No one was able to figure-out what was going on. Finally, they put me in touch with the person who implemented and maintains the unit testing framework for VS. We also went through a couple of remote sessions with their developer examining my system. On the latest session he finally figured-out what was failing.

The test app launched by visual studio uses the local network to send the unit testing results to the IDE app. **If there is more than one network adapter on your computer, the unit testing framework can get confused and try communicating with the IDE via the wrong network adapter.** Thus, the VS TestExplorer just hangs there waiting for a response from the test app while the test app hangs there trying to find the TestExplorer over the wrong network.

**The workaround:** My development system has three network adapters: Ethernet, Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. Disabling both the unused Bluetooth and Wi-Fi adapters forced the unit testing framework to locate the IDE on the correct adapter. After that, the unit testing started to function again. Once it started working, I was able to re-enable the other two adapters. I assume that if it fails again, then I would have to go through the same process.

Microsoft will eventually include a fix for this problem in a future build of Visual Studio, but until that time, you can remedy the issue by disabling the unused network adapters, run the unit tests so they can locate the  TestExplorer, and then re-enable the adapters.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. It's unfortunate that this didn't solve it for me, but it was at least something else to look at.

Comment: @NathanStrutz: Unfortunately, the issue returned in VS 2017 after a recent update to Windows. And this workaround doesn't help either. To address this, Microsoft's tech support wants us to pay another $500 US to open a second support incident, on top of the $500 we already paid. We are not going to pay MS to help them debug *their* software. I'll use a different machine for testing. I'll post any new information here if MS changes their mind. In the meantime, I'd advise developers to look elsewhere for a unit testing platform.

Comment: Microsoft pushed out update to Visual Studio 2017 today, version 15.7.0. It included a major revamping of the unit testing framework. Now, the last machine that I had a working unit testing framework on crashes when I try to run the tests. The stack trace in the output window indicates that it's crashing in their code. Why am I not surprised? Ever since Visual Studio 2015, what was once one of the best IDEs in the business has gotten slower and buggier with EVERY update--that is NOT hyperbole. SMH.